# multidimensional associative array - difference

Tags: php

How to compare multidimensional associative arrays.

Some function like: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#98680

For example ArrayDiff should be the result of comparing Array1 and Array2. Showing elements with different value and new elements.

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 39.00
            [time] => 0.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 49.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 0.00
            [Value] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 49.00
            [time] => 0.00
        )
)

Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 39.00
            [time] => 10.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 49.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 0.00
            [Value] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 49.00
            [time] => 0.00
            [Value] => 3
        )
)


ArrayDiff
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 10.00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Value] => 3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
$arrayDiff = array_map('array_diff_assoc', $array1, $array2);
```

Maybe follow that with `array_filter($arrayDiff)` if you want to get rid of the empty (equal) elements.